# How much additional heat does sunlight add to a building? (estimate)

Tags: hvac

I'm adding air conditioning units the the second floor (UK) of a manor house, and estimating the output needed for AC units. I know the heat gain from walls, window, and roof, as I know the U-values of these surfaces, comparing the temp inside and outside.
I would also like to know the heat gain due to sunlight throughout the day, and how that increases the amount of AC output I'll need. It doesn't need to be exact, just a 'best practices' answer like "increase it by 10-20%" will be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you have the info for walls and windows, so now include hours of sunshine, angle, and things like shading etc

Answer (score 1):

In the US, the most common method is called the Model J method.  It includes ambient temps and sun loads.  It is more or less a standardized approach to the calculations in the ASHRAE Fundamentals book (again, US-centric).  Model J calculations are generally required by code enforcement over here.  Various software exists to do this as well.

I assume there is a UK equivalent, and also that it would be better than the US-based on due to different construction methods for residential structure, not to mention environment differences.